# how to solve recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap exception?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a activity,my activity contains ImageView and two buttons.I have assign drawable animation to ImageView.when u click on next button animation will be change before animation change just i clear drawable animation frames using following code,

```
            loadingAnimation.stop();//drawable animation object
        for (int i = 0; i < loadingAnimation.getNumberOfFrames(); ++i){
            Drawable frame = loadingAnimation.getFrame(i);
            if (frame instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                ((BitmapDrawable)frame).getBitmap().recycle();
            }
            frame.setCallback(null);
        }
        loadingAnimation.setCallback(null);
```

It is working fine for Next Button.we move A1(animation1) to A2(animation2) just click on next button.if we want move back to A2 to A1 just click on previous button.When u click on previous button for move back to A2 to A1 i got exception like,

```
Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap
```

please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Drawable frame = loadingAnimation.getFrame(i); 

 if ((null != frame && ((BitmapDrawable)frame).getBitmap().isRecycled())) { 

 ((BitmapDrawable)frame).getBitmap().recycle(); 
 } else { 

 log("bitmap is already recycled"); 
 } 

 frame = null;
```

Something like this atleast, maybe you need to change it to fit your code perfectly.

Comment: i have added this 'if(((BitmapDrawable) frame).getBitmap()!=null)' same problem.

Comment: When you click on "previous" you have to use the getBitmap again, because now you delete it when you click on next, then later you try to display the deleted bitmap.

Comment: how to use getBitmap() please help me

Comment: What happens when you change this line:
 `((BitmapDrawable)frame).getBitmap().recycle();`
into : `((BitmapDrawable)frame).getBitmap();`

Comment: when i click on previous button if(getBitmap=null) then will call to ((BitmapDrawable)frame).getBitmap(); right

Comment: Changed answer, think it should indeed be something like this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8587/discussion-between-chiru-and-bigflow)

Comment: @Bigflow you are skipping the bitmap recycle. That's why code is working. You are recycling the bitmap if already recycled. And thus bitmap never get recycled.

Answer (score 0):

It crashes because when you press back it tries to load the frames you deleted. You should either not delete them or not use them after you delete.

Comment: i have no.of drawable animation,if i dont delete frames it is crashing and exception is "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget"